# How does jQuery calculate the callback variable values?

Tags: jquery, callback, formula

jQuery always appends 2 GET variables at the end of the url like this:

```
callback=jQuery172010710813803598285_1362438925287&_=1362438934989
```

But how do they calculate these numbers? I've found out that the first 10 signs of tha last 2 numbers are the current timestamp, but I cannot figure out what the 3 last numbers stand for. Or how the first part is created. Anyone who knows this?

Thanks!

Comment: That seems like it was done by some custom implementation.

Comment: Why? Its trying to be as random as possible.

Comment: Because it was the only thing that they could still test server-side and then this would be the reason why my curl script wasn't working on the server. It's not completely random.

Comment: It isn't as random as possible, it's as **unique** as possible. It's generated in such a way that no two simultaneous requests will use the same name, while limiting the total number of different names generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is created using this:

```
jsonpCallback: function() {
    var callback = oldCallbacks.pop() || ( jQuery.expando + "_" + ( ajax_nonce++ ) );
    this[ callback ] = true;
    return callback;
}
```

first, it tries to use a previously used callback if one exists. If none, then it uses `jQuery.expando` (which is `"jQuery" + ( core_version + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" )` and `+ "_" + ( ajax_nonce++ )` where `ajax_nonce` is `$.now()` calculated at the time jQuery was initialized. This ensures a unique callback name regardless of how fast you send out the requests.

with this in mind, i can assume you're using jQuery 1.7.2 and need to update, :p

Answer (score 0):

By using some function which tries to provide as many random and unique numbers it can. Some thing like `uniqid()`([Link](http://phpjs.org/functions/uniqid/)) function.